# jQuery Expander Number of elements

Tags: jquery, expander

i'm using [expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/index.html#getting-started) for a web-project

so i need to count elements that a visible before "Read More" is clicked, can somebody help me ?

Comment: Did you try the `:visible` selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these elements have some class, say "testClass", you cand select them ($( ".testClass" )), iterate over them (.each function) and verify what element is visible (using attr( "style" ) or css( "display" ) functions) and count them. You can use the "is" function too in this way is(":visible").